# The smallest signed 16 bit number in decimal is

Tags: assembly, unsigned, signed

I am trying to figure out this question for my Assembly Language Class.

12. The smallest **signed** 16 bit number in decimal is ______

My Professor said that my answer of
`-32768`
is wrong. How do I figure this out correctly?

13 The largest **unsigned** 8 bit number in decimal is _______

My answer is`255`. Is this correct?

Comment: The smallest 16-bit signed number depends on the representation for signed numbers. While most modern architectures use two's complement, historically machines have also used signed magnitude or one's complement representations.

Comment: Your answer of -32768 is correct, assuming two's complement representation. Your answer of 255 is correct.

Comment: The professor said no negative numbers?

Comment: @Peggy The smallest non-negative number doesn't depend on the size of the type. It's zero.

Comment: What architecture/processor is used in your class?

Comment: You should edit the non-negative requirement into the question.  "smallest" might mean minimum (`MIN_INT`, compares `<=` to any other signed 16bit int), or it might mean smallest *magnitude*, like your professor seems to mean.  That's fairly arbitrary.

Answer (score 4):

12. It depends of representation:

In two's complement: -(2^15) = -32768

sign/magnitude: -(2^15-1) = -32767

13. 255 is correct

Comment: Your answer for sign/magnitude should be -32767. Also, 'complement' != 'compliment'.